# Batch Programming --- Moving multiple files

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to make a Batch File that creates folders, then moves the amount of files into each file that I specify.
I am able to pull it off but I don't want 10k lines of data.
I don't want more than 1000 files in each folder.

Lets say I have a total of 1,000 files in the %CD% with names ranging from 1.jpg to 1000.jpg and if I choose to make 2 folders with 50 files to be moved into each folder how can I do this?
So I want (1.jpg to 50.jpg) to be moved to folder 1 and (51.jpg to 100.jpg) to be moved to folder 2.
It works the way I'm doing it, but if I make a total of 5 Folders with 1,000 files in each folder I'm looking at over 10k lines of data.
Here is what I have so far.

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
CLS
ECHO.
SET /P M=How Many Folders Do You Want To Make Up to 5 Total:
cls
SET /P Count=How Many Files Do You Want To Move To Each Folder:
cls
set /p Type=What Format are the files:
cls
set /a Two="%Count% * %M%"

IF %M%==5 goto 5Folder
IF %M%==4 goto 4Folder
IF %M%==3 goto 3Folder
IF %M%==2 goto 2Folder
IF %M%==1 goto 1Folder
:5Folder
CLS
@echo off
mkdir 5
Timeout /t 3
Xcopy Menu.* "%cd%\5\"

:4Folder
CLS
@echo off
mkdir 4
Timeout /t 3
Xcopy Menu.* "%cd%\4\"
:3Folder
CLS
@echo off
mkdir 3
Timeout /t 3
Xcopy Menu.* "%cd%\3\"
:2Folder
CLS
@echo off
mkdir 2
Timeout /t 3
Xcopy Menu.* "%cd%\2\"
:1Folder
CLS
@echo off
mkdir 1
Timeout /t 3
Xcopy Menu.* "%cd%\1\"


:One
CLS
goto :%Count%One
:5One
move /-y "%cd%\5.%Type%" "%cd%\1\"
:4One
move /-y "%cd%\4.%Type%" "%cd%\1\"
:3One
move /-y "%cd%\3.%Type%" "%cd%\1\"
:2One
move /-y "%cd%\2.%Type%" "%cd%\1\"
:1One
move /-y "%cd%\1.%Type%" "%cd%\1\"


:Two
cls
goto :%Two%Two
:5Two
move /-y "%cd%\5.%Type%" "%cd%\2\"
:4Two
move /-y "%cd%\4.%Type%" "%cd%\2\"
:3Two
move /-y "%cd%\3.%Type%" "%cd%\2\"
:2Two
move /-y "%cd%\2.%Type%" "%cd%\2\"
:1Two
move /-y "%cd%\1.%Type%" "%cd%\2\"
```

Comment: In your given example, out of 1000 files you want to create two (2) directories and place fifty (50) files in each directory. That will still leave 900 files in the original location. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I just need a reference to go by.